# Duplicate Key Value SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, on-duplicate-key

I have a table where I need to insert codes, years, and descriptions. When the table was created, the PKey was Year,Code  I'm trying to insert the same code with a different year into the table

So...

Existing values

```
Year  | Code| Description
2016  |  A  |  Code A
2016  |  B  |  Code B
2016  |  C  |  Code C
```

Attempt to Insert

```
2017  |  A  |  Code A
2017  |  B  |  Code B
2017  |  C  |  Code C
```

From what I've read, it sounds like this should be valid. But, for some reason, I keep getting the error that

My SQL is:

```
select *
into #temp
from code_lkp

insert into code_lkp (year,code,description)
select 2017,code,description
from #temp

drop table #temp
```

Since the combination of the two columns is unique, shouldn't the table accept the insert?

UPDATE....

I ran

```
select a.name, b.name, c.name
from sys.sysobjects a
inner join sys.syscolumns b
on a.id = b.id
inner join sys.key_constraints c
on c.parent_object_id = a.id
where a.type = 'U'
and a.name = 'code_lkp'
```

According to the results:

```
SysObjects | SysColumns | key_contraints
code_lkp   | Year       | code_lkp_pk
code_lkp   | Code       | code_lkp_pk
```

If I'm not mistaken, this should indicate that both Year and Code are part of the same Primary Key.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the `#temp` table?  Are you certain you're only trying to insert each combination once?

Comment: I can't show the contents of the temp table. But, basically, it follows as in the example. I'm only trying to insert each combination once (1x). So, I want 2017,A in there once. 2018, A in there once... etc.

Comment: Should also mention, the temp table is created in the select into statement.

Comment: Run your insert statement with the `Insert` line commented out and see what is being selected.  It sounds like you are trying to insert the same record twice.

Comment: it's coming back with 2017 || A, 2017|| B, 2017|| C. Those values are not in the target table.

Comment: Without seeing your data, I'm honestly not sure what to tell you.  I've recreated your tables with the data given, and run your exact queries and it worked without any issues.

Comment: I'll keep digging. Thanks!! There may be something else going on with this system that I'm not privy to ATM.

Comment: You might also want to check to see if there are any triggers on that table. The error could be coming from one of those, instead.

Comment: I did check for triggers. Nothing present.  URGH

Comment: Add real `CREATE TABLE` script for `code_lkp`

Comment: I would check the DDL for the primary key to ensure it is looking at both Year and Code.

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: I updated above. From what I can tell (querying the sys.key_contraints), it looks like both Year and Code are part of the same primary key.

Comment: The error is always "Violation of primary key constraint code_lkp_pk. Cannot insert duplicate key object 'dbo.code_lkp'. The duplicate key is (2017, A)

Comment: I'm thinking your select statement is not returning distinct values, meaning that you have multiple rows with 2017, A values

Comment: That appears to be the issue. I ran a general select query. It looks like all the values are in there now.

Comment: please post `show create table` result.

Comment: The issue was resolved. It was a problem of not using the Distinct operator in the select query when selecting into the temp table. ..... thanks Sparrow.